# Return highest-ranked row in each group

Tags: sql, t-sql, plsql

I need to find the highest-valued row in each group in a table, e.g., I want to group the following by Color and Shape, and then take the row with the highest Cost. E.g. for input

```
ID Color Shape    Cost
-- ----- -----    ----
1  Red   Round    45
2  Red   Round    18
3  Red   Square   13
4  Red   Square   92
5  Green Round    25
6  Green Round    21
7  Green Triangle 20
8  Green Triangle 33
```

I want to get

```
ID Color Shape    Cost
-- ----- -----    ----
1  Red   Round    45
4  Red   Square   92
5  Green Round    25
8  Green Triangle 33
```

How can I do this? Something that works on PL/SQL and T/SQL would be fantastic, although my immediate need is PL/SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to partition on color and shape and then assign 1 as row number to the highest cost in that partition.

```
select id,color,shape,cost
from
(
select *, 
row_number() over(partition by color,shape order by cost desc) as rn
from tablename
) t 
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a really basic solution to the problem then your best bet is below. this will work in almost any SQL variation.

Also believe it or not this is faster then the flash 'row_number()' version.
but we are talking micro second. so its really just a matter of preference.

A working example below

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (ID INT,Colour NVARCHAR(16),Shape NVARCHAR(16),Cost INT)
INSERT INTO @Data
VALUES
(1,'Red'  ,'Round',   45),
(2,'Red'  ,'Round',   18),
(3,'Red'  ,'Square',  13),
(4,'Red'  ,'Square',  92),
(5,'Green','Round',   25),
(6,'Green','Round',   21),
(7,'Green','Triangle',20),
(8,'Green','Triangle',33)

SELECT      D.ID,
            D.Colour,
            D.Shape,
            G.Cost
FROM        @Data AS D
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT      Colour,Shape,MAX(Cost) AS Cost
    FROM        @Data
    GROUP BY    Colour,Shape
) AS G ON G.Colour = D.Colour AND G.Shape = D.Shape AND G.Cost = D.Cost
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a straight forward SELECT statement if you have your table setup - we'll call it table_a:

```
SELECT id, color, shape, max(cost) as Cost
from table_a
group by id, color, shape
```

Not sure about the output allowing for Cost to be capitalized in your output - sometimes this depends on your SQL Syntax. (not possible in IMPALA SQL for instance)

Comment: The Id in your groupby means this will not work. Check the expected result

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using co-related sub query, shown below:

```
select id,color,shape,cost 
from ex_1 a where cost = (select max(cost) 
                      from ex_1 b 
                      where a.shape = b.shape 
                      and a.color = b.color)
```

I named the table as ex_1 having 8 entries and a,b are table alias used in example.